# How to check if an item has already been selected on a subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following vba code to check wether a product is already selected on a subform. And then alert the user.

```
Private Sub ProdId_Combo_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim icount As Long
  icount = Nz(DCount("[ProdID]", "ProdRestockDetails", "[ProdID]=" & Me.ProdID & " AND RestockID=" & Me.RestockID, 0))
    If icount <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "this item has already been selected."
       Cancel = True
       Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

But it throws an error.
Can someone help me set it correctly please?

Comment: Where is your error occurring?  Is your ProdID numeric (and same with RestockID)?  If they're text fields, you'll need to add quotes.  e.g.  icount = DCount("[ProdID]", "ProdRestockDetails", "[ProdID]='" & Me.ProdID & "' AND RestockID='" & Me.RestockID & "'")

Comment: They are both autonumber. Nb: when I use only the ProdId it works, but when I add the RestockID in the where clause it throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Dcount and Nz functions aren't ended appropriately.  Can you try this?  Also with the DCount function you shouldn't need the Nz wrapper because if the value isn't found a zero should be returned.

```
Private Sub ProdId_Combo_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim icount As Long
  icount = Nz(DCount("[ProdID]", "ProdRestockDetails", "[ProdID]=" & Me.ProdID & " AND RestockID=" & Me.RestockID), 0)
    If icount <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "this item has already been selected."
       Cancel = True
       Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wonderfull. It does the job. Thanks RyanL